# Connect with a secured Hbase using a java client

Tags: java, connection, client, hbase, kerberos

I am trying to connect with a securized hbase with kerberos. It is an hbase deployed into a hdp3 cluster. Exactly, I am trying to access with a java client from a host that is outside the cluster.

This is my code:

```
System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","/etc/krb5.conf");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("java.security.debug", "gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext");
        System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "hbase.conf");

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();

        String principal="user@REALM";
        File keytab = new File("/home/user/user.keytab");

        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, keytab.getAbsolutePath());

        ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void run() {

                try {

                    TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("some_table");
                    final Connection conn = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
                    System.out.println(" go ");
                    Table table = conn.getTable(tableName);
                    Result r = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("some_key")));
                    System.out.println(r);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }
        });

    }
```

This is my jaas file conf:

```
Client {
  com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
  useKeyTab=true
  useTicketCache=false
  keyTab="/home/user/user.keytab"
  principal="user@REALM";
};
```

All the zookeeper and other config is taken from the hbase-site.xml file provided by ambari.

I get no error just the client get in a infinite loop with a trace like:

ReadOnlyZKClient-node2:2181,node3:2181,node4:2181@0x50ad3bc1-SendThread(node4:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x371f62d9b230031, packet:: clientPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 141,4 replyHeader:: 141,365072222881,0 request:: '/hbase-secure/meta-region-server,F response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a313630303019fffffff6ffffff864dffffff99ffffff85151c50425546a11a56e6f64653410ffffff947d18ffffffb0ffffffa6ffffff81ffffffc5ffffff9f2e100183,s{365072220963,365072222074,1588973398227,1589014218472,5,0,0,0,52,0,365072220963} [ReadOnlyZKClient-node2:2181,node3:2181,node4:2181@0x50ad3bc1-SendThread(node4:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x371f62d9b230031, packet:: clientPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 142,4 replyHeader:: 142,365072222881,0 request:: '/hbase-secure/meta-region-server,F response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a313630303019fffffff6ffffff864dffffff99ffffff85151c50425546a11a56e6f64653410ffffff947d18ffffffb0ffffffa6ffffff81ffffffc5ffffff9f2e100183,s{365072220963,365072222074,1588973398227,1589014218472,5,0,0,0,52,0,365072220963} [ReadOnlyZKClient-node2:2181,node3:2181,node4:2181@0x50ad3bc1-SendThread(node4:2181)] DEBUG org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Reading reply sessionid:0x371f62d9b230031, packet:: clientPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server serverPath:/hbase-secure/meta-region-server finished:false header:: 143,4 replyHeader:: 143,365072222881,0 request:: '/hbase-secure/meta-region-server,F response:: #ffffffff000146d61737465723a313630303019fffffff6ffffff864dffffff99ffffff85151c50425546a11a56e6f64653410ffffff947d18ffffffb0ffffffa6ffffff81ffffffc5ffffff9f2e100183,s{365072220963,365072222074,1588973398227,1589014218472,5,0,0,0,52,0,365072220963}

**EDIT**

OK i got this error just I was not waited enougth:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=1200000, callDuration=2350283: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Mon May 11 13:53:42 CEST 2020, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=70631: Call to slave-5.cluster/172.10.96.43:16020 failed on local exception: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] row 'tome_table,some_key,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=slave-5.cluster/172.10.96.43:16020,16020,1588595144765, seqNum=-1
 row 'row_key' on table 'some_table' at null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:386)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.get(HTable.java:360)
    at internal.holly.devoptools.hbase.HBaseCli.main(HBaseCli.java:77)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
Mon May 11 13:53:42 CEST 2020, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=70631: Call to slave-5.cluster/172.10.96.43:16020 failed on local exception: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)] row 'some_table,some_key,99999999999999' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=slave-5.cluster,16020,1588595144765, seqNum=-1

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.throwEnrichedException(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:298)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:242)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:192)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:269)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.loadCache(ClientScanner.java:437)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextWithSyncCache(ClientScanner.java:312)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.next(ClientScanner.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(ConnectionImplementation.java:856)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:759)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:745)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionImplementation.java:716)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionImplementation.getRegionLocation(ConnectionImplementation.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HRegionLocator.getRegionLocation(HRegionLocator.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RegionServerCallable.prepare(RegionServerCallable.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerImpl.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCallerImpl.java:105)
    ... 3 more
```

Thanks.

Comment: Side question: why use both a raw JAAS config **and** a Hadoop UGI, which overrides most of JAAS default behavior (unless JAAS screws up the UGI first)?

Comment: Also, do you have a good reason not to use the default, _static_ UGI object -- and use the explicit `doAs`construct on an explicit UGI object instead?

Comment: I would advise using `core-site.xml` besides `hbase-site.xml` since HBase uses some core Hadoop libs, and these have Kerberos settings too.

Comment: I was just doing a lot of tries. Just because, I dont understand how the connection is done. For example which rights are required to connect with zookeeper which one are required to connect with hbase.

Comment: Two facts I learnt the hard way: (a) mixing JAAS settings and Hadoop UGI settings is dangerous, (b) when connecting to HBase the logs from ZK libraries are useless and distracting because the "intelligence" is managed by the HBase libs -- I advise to tweak the Log4J settings to silence ZK completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally adding this prop it worked:

```
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");
```

And this is my final code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "/etc/krb5.conf");

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

        String principal = "user@REALM";

        UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
        UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principal, "/home/user/principal.keytab");

        Connection conn = ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<Connection>() {
            @Override
            public Connection run() throws Exception {
                return ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
            }
        });

        TableName tableName = TableName.valueOf("some_table");
        Table table = conn.getTable(tableName);
        Result r = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes("some_key")));

        System.out.println("result: " + r);

    }
```

Comment: Yep, that one comes from `core-site.xml`

Comment: Thanks very much Samson, now I just wondering if it is possible to configure a local hbase to use it as client only just the hbase shell. I was trying to configure it but I dont know how to do it. I dont know how to configure the  UserGroupInformation thing in the hbase shell.

Comment: With a CLI _(command-line interface utility)_ you can't use any code or API. Just create a Kerberos ticket and store it in the local Linux cache with `kinit` and let the CLI retrieve the ticket when needed _(or rather, let the UGI inside the CLI check the cache)_

Comment: That is exactly what I want. But hbase shell dont use UGI therefore when I configure it with kerberos it doesnt work.

Comment: Beware, newer Linux versions may use by default `KEYRING:` to cache the Kerberos tickets, while Hadoop supports only the legacy `FILE:` cache. Check out with `klist` -- and if necessary, change the cache specification inside `/etc/krb5.conf` or via env variable `KRB5CCNAME`

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue; in my case, while I was submitting the spark job, I had included the hadoop* and hbase* jars in my spark-submit command; After a some inspections, I noticed that I  had included hadoop* and hbase* jars which do not match the same versions of the hbase/hadoop in my yarn cluster. It was a minor difference in those jars, but it messed up the kerberos authentication